# Code not connecting to MQTT local server

Tags: arduino, mqtt

I am trying to connect my Arduino Uno with WiFi shield to my MQTT server. I am running it local on my Mac. It seems to be stuck in the while loop. I think it doesn't connect to the broker. Here is my code. What could be the problem with the loop? Or is there another problem?

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <MQTTClient.h>

const char ssid[] = " : /*filed in*: ";
const char pass[] = " /*filed in*/ ";

WiFiClient net;
MQTTClient client;

unsigned long lastMillis = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

  // Note: Local domain names (e.g. "Computer.local" on OSX) are not supported by Arduino.
  // You need to set the IP address directly.
  client.begin("10.0.1.5", net);
  client.onMessage(messageReceived);

  connect();
}

void connect() {
  Serial.print("checking wifi...");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println("wifi connected");

  Serial.print("\nconnecting...");
  while (!client.connect("Arduino test")) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.println("\nconnected!");
  Serial.println("connected");

  client.subscribe("hello");
  // client.unsubscribe("/hello");
}

void loop() {
  client.loop();

  if (!client.connected()) {
    connect();
    Serial.print("not");
  }

  // publish a message roughly every second.
  if (millis() - lastMillis > 1000) {
    lastMillis = millis();
    client.publish("hello world");
  }
}

void messageReceived(String &topic, String &payload) {
  Serial.println("incoming: " + topic + " - " + payload);
}
```

Comment: Have you turned off any firewall on the Mac? Also edit the question to include the serial output from the arduino so we can see what message it prints out

Comment: Also again you've just posted code and said "this doesn't work" with no evidence that you've tried to debug it yourself. Unless you include the output that's been asked for I'll flag this for closing